# O que é e como funcionam os npm @types?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Estou iniciando um projeto com `NodeJS` e `TypeScript` e o instrutor falou para instalar o `@types/node`, além do pacote npm do `TypeScript`. Ele citou rapidamente que o `@types/node` cria tipos no `TypeScript` para entidades do `Node`, mas gostaria de uma explicação mais aprofundada de como isso funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este pacote no escopo `@types` é onde podemos encontrar varias definições de tipo úteis, como, por exemplo, as definições de tipo do Node que nos permitem usar, por exemplo, o `require` para importar modulos.

O pacote `@types` do Node contem definições de tipo para muitas bibliotecas, como Express, Sequelize, JQuery e muitas outras. Basicamente o que ele faz e:

- verifique se o pacote que você está usando já possui tipos
  incorporados e, se preferir, prefira estes;
- verifique se as definições de tipo já foram enviadas com o
  compilador.

Este link: [Typescript Typings - The Complete Guide To Type Definitions: @types, Compiler Opt-In Types: When To Use Each and Why?](https://blog.angular-university.io/typescript-2-type-system-how-do-type-definitions-work-in-npm-when-to-use-types-and-why-what-are-compiler-opt-in-types/) possui material para explicacao de Types e acho que vale a pena da uma olhada. Espero ter ajudado.